# MySQL LOAD DATA is removing leading zeros in varchar field

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've got a data import routine which accepts CSV files, the first column of which contain a character dataset consisting of ID values in the format 0123, 0517, 1531, etc.  Typically 4 digits with a leading zero on the 3 digit number.

The data is being loaded into a table using a varchar(255) field but when I call the LOAD DATA command it's all being imported without the leading zero.  Is there something I'm missing here?

```
db_query('CREATE TABLE feed_buildings (
  BLDGID varchar(255),
  BLDGNAME varchar(255),
  CITY varchar(255),
  STATE varchar(255),
  ZIPCODE varchar(255),
  LLRDID varchar(255),
  BLDGGLA varchar(255),
  ADDRESS1 varchar(255),
  ADDRESS2 varchar(255),
  NMBRUNIT varchar(255),
  MNGRID varchar(255),
  INACTIVE varchar(255),
  OCCGLA varchar(255) )', false, false);
```

In this example it's the BLDGID field that's losing its leading zeros when I run the following command:

```
$loadfields = ' ( BLDGID, BLDGNAME, CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE, LLRDID, @ignore, BLDGGLA, @ignore, ADDRESS1, 
  ADDRESS2, @ignore, @ignore, NMBRUNIT, MNGRID, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, 
  @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, INACTIVE, @ignore, 
  @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, @ignore, OCCGLA )';

$loadquery = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'' . $path . '\' INTO TABLE feed_buildings . ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\' IGNORE 1 LINES';
db_query_unprepared($loadquery . $loadfields);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: are you sure that zero is in your csv file? and why do you use a varchar255 if you are going to store a 4 digit number?

Comment: Yeah, I double-checked that.  I see the zero if I open the CSV in Notepad.  And this is just a temporary table which I then operate on to merge with my main tables so for simplicity's sake I make all the columns the same.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard -- I'm not sure how it happened the first few times but the last few are importing properly.